# Hiding Button content once mouse is no longer present JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, state

I have been trying to get my search bar to disappear when the mouse is not hovering over the element any longer. I'm thinking it's because its a button and not a `li` but if possible I would like to do both.
[image]

```
    <div class="dropdown">
     <button onclick="regionSearch()" class="dropbtn">search by Region</button>
       <div id="regionSearch" class="dropdown-content">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="regionInput" 
          onkeyup="regionFilter()">
      <a href="north-island/bop/bop.html">Bay of Plenty</a>
      <a href="north-island/auckland/auckland.html">Auckland</a>
      <a href="north-island/northland/northland.html">Northland</a>
      <a href="north-island/waikato/waikato">Waikato</a>
      <a href="north-island/gisborne/gisborne">Gisborne</a>
      <a href="north-island/hawkesbay/hawkesbay.html">Hawkes Bay</a>
      <a href="north-island/wellington/wellington.html">Wellington</a>
      <a href="north-island/taranaki/taranaki.html">Taranaki</a>
      <a href="north-island/manawatu/manawatu.html">Manawatu</a>
      <a href="south-island/tasmon/tasmon.html">Tasmon</a>
      <a href="south-island/nelson/nelson.html">Nelson</a>
      <a href="south-island/malborough/malborough.htm;">Malborough</a>
      <a href="south-island/westcoast.westcoast.html">West Coast</a>
      <a href="south-island/canterbury/canterbury.html">Canterbury</a>
      <a href="south-island/otago/otago.html">Otago</a>
  </div>
</div>

              function citySearch() {
    document.getElementById("citySearch").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("citySearch");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I have more then one element styled this way.

```
#myInput,#regionInput,#diffInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

all of this code is functional and works fine but just looks and feels outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment if i could instead of replying a whole answer, though this may be a solution to you - you don't *have* to use JS for this affect.

Like you used on your dropdown classes in your CSS file, you can do

```
#searchbox{ display: none; } /* default is not displayed / no mouse hover
#searchbox:hover{ display: inline-block; } /* upon mouse hover, show the search
```

To add, I once had the feeling as you do. I tried to make a whole javascript drop down hover menu from scratch, but it literally took 2 lines of CSS code.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have tried this route and nothing happened :/ im thinking its because its a button so it has to be clicked to drop down the content, ive tried your suggestion in every way i can think possible with css but nothing works :/ is there a way to target the html button to hide its content once its clicked and the user has moved there mouse off, at the minute the button has to be closed manually and its not very user friendly.

Comment: You can switch it from a button to a `<span>` or `<div>`, both can do the trick and allow the css `:hover` modifier to work better than with a button, as yes, buttons do need to be clicked though the `:hover` will work on all HTMl elements.

Answer (score 0):

thank you zatyh for the idea to change the button to a div as it inspired me to do the following in my html

```
<div onmouseover="diffSearch()" onclick="diffSearch()" 
 onmouseout="hideDiff()"class="dropbtn">search by Difficulty</div>
```

//and added the hideDiff function to my javascript file

```
function hideDiff(){ x=document.getElementByid("diffSearch"); x.style.display("none");}
```

this works, theres still a few bugs on the flow of it